# Tutorial Using R on an Amazon Ec2 using just browser for building a regression model

Tags: r, amazon-ec2

Assume I have huge huge data and no money for hardware for more RAM for R AND software like Windows or any non open source

. Just an internet connection. and an university Amazon ec2 account.

Could you please guide me to a step by step- copy and paste coding tutorial on building a model using any Package on Amazon ec2.

Note- I know BIOCEP can do this, and Robert Grossman gave a tutorial on using R on Amazon Ec2. I just need a tutorial that say uses a R GUI like Rattle to build model on Amazon Ec2.

Assume I am a statistican with no knowledge of Amazon ec2 or using R there

Comment: Can we assume that these assumptions all actually apply to you and your situation? :)

Answer (score 4):

Karen Chine gave a presentation on using BIOCEP at UseR 2009.  It's not quite step-by-step, but it may get you started.

http://www2.agrocampus-ouest.fr/math/useR-2009/slides/Chine.pdf